# String made NUL after function cal

Tags: c, string, pointers

I am trying to recreate the C++ function `std::string.pop_back` in C, where the last non-NUL character of the input string is popped off.  In the `pop_back` function below the variable `out` has the desired output of the function, but trying to reassign `*string` to be `out` makes `*string` be the correct value before the function closes (for example, if I were to print `string*` at the end of the function, it would output `Hello World`), but in `main()`, after `pop_back()` is called, `string` is output as blank.  What am I doing wrong in reassigning `string`?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void pop_back(char** string) {
    size_t stringLen = strlen(*string);
    char out[stringLen];

    strxfrm(out, *string, stringLen);
    // Here *string == "Hello World!"
    *string = out;
    // Here *string == "Hello World"
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    char* string = "Hello World!";
    printf("Initial string: %s\n", string);
    pop_back(&string);
    printf("After pop_back: %s\n", string);
    return 0;
}

// Output:
// $ ./pop_back_test
// Initial string: Hello World!
// After pop_back: 

// Expected output:
// $ ./pop_back_test
// Initial string: Hello World!
// After pop_back: Hello World
```

Comment: In the `pop_back` function, what is `out` (in regards to scope and life-time)? What will happen to `out` once the function returns?

Comment: With `char* string = "Hello World!";
` you are assigning a read-ony string to the pointer. That will probably result in a seg fault or so when you try to modify it. Use `char string[] = {"Hello World!"};`

Comment: `out` stops existing when `pop_back` returns, but you try to print its contents in main

Comment: `char out[stringLen];` is _local_ variable. You cannot retun it as in `*string = out;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With your code

```
char out[stringLen];
...
*string = out;
```

You "return" (assign to a parameter) a pointer to a "local variable", i.e. a pointer to an object with automatic storage duration, which's life time ends at the end of the function. Accessing an object beyond its lifetime is undefined behaviour.

You probably have to dynamically allocate a new string, which you can then manipulate and use after function execution has ended. For example:

```
if (!(*string) || !(**string)) {
  // decide what to do with NULL or empty input strings.
  ...
}
else {
  size_t stringLen = strlen(*string);
  char* out = malloc(stringLen);
  memcpy(out, *string, stringLen);
  out[stringLen-1] = '\0';
} 

*string = out;
```

Don't forget to free allocated memory afterwards. BTW: if you operate on a copy, I'd suggest to return the (new) copy and leave the input pointer as is, i.e. I'd change the prototype to

```
char* pop_back(char* string) {
    ...
    return out;
}
```

Comment: > Don't forget to free allocated memory afterwards.

You forgot it in your code snippet.

Comment: For allocating a new string, I'd expect a +1 as in `char* out = malloc(stringLen + 1);
  memcpy(out, *string, stringLen + 1);` and `*string = out;` within the `else`.

Comment: @chux: It's because the last character is to be cut off, that's why `stringLen` and not `stringLen+1`; Otherwise I would have used `strcpy` or `strdup`...

Comment: @S.M.: with parameter `char** string`, we must not assume that we have control over the memory to which `*string` points to. Freeing it in the function would lead to undefined behaviour if the memory were not allocated using `malloc`; That's why I suggested to change the prototype to `char* pop(char* string)`...

Answer (score 2):

As I step through your code, the message in my debugger indicates on line...

```
*string = out;
```

...that `*string` is over array bounds, failing the assignment.  `*string` points to a *[string literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20547979/c-string-immutable)* which means among other things it cannot be modified. Attempting to modify its content will always fail.

There are several ways this can be remedied.

One way is to modify your `pop_back()` function to accept a `char *`, and return a `char *`, allowing you to pass in an immutable string and return the resulting string.

Suggested implementation:

```
char * pop_back(char *string) 
{
    size_t stringLen = strlen(string)+1;//add one for NULL
    char *out = calloc(stringLen,1);//create space for new string

    strxfrm(out, string, stringLen);
    // Here *string == "Hello World!"
    return out;//return string
    // Here *string == "Hello World"
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) 
{
    char *string1 = "Hello World!";         // source string
    char *string2 = {0};                    // container for local result

    printf("Initial string: %s\n", string1);
    string2 = pop_back(string1);            // get local result
    printf("After pop_back: %s\n", string2);// use local result
    free(string2);                          // free local result
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *`*string` points to a string literal ,,, [that] ceases to exist once execution flow leaves the function it was created in*  No. String literals are *static*. Per **6.4.5 String literals**, paragraph 6 of [the C Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):  "In  translation  phase  7,  ... a string literal or literals.
The multibyte character
sequence  is  then  used  to  initialize  an  array  of  static  storage  duration  and  length  just
sufficient  to  contain  the  sequence."

Comment: @AndrewHenle - I have edited out the incorrect statements about `string literals`. (I learned something)  Thanks again.